# How can I golf this code to count all perfect squares below 100?

Tags: code-golf, math, tips, python

I'm trying to strip down my python code to be as few lines as possible. The task: count how many square numbers are below 100. Here's my code so far:

```python
m = 0
for x in range(0, 100):
    m+=1-(-((-((x+1)**(0.5)-((x+1)**(0.5))//1))//1));
print(m)
```

That addition statement adds 1 to m (the counter) only when (x+1) is a perfect square. Is it possible to shorten anything? Maybe find a way to print without using a counter -- such as printing a summation in a form such as:

```python
print(sum(min,max,variable,statement))
```

Comment: `print(9)` works :P

Comment: To close voters: [tips] are on topic.

Comment: I mean, you can get rid of the semicolon on your third line.

Comment: You say you want to count how many square numbers are below 100, but you're counting how many are between 1 and 100 inclusive. Which is it?

Comment: Have you taken a look at out [Python golf tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/20260)? In particular, there's some easy gains from removing whitespace and parentheses. I think asking for particular advice for this particular golf is putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: You could quite easily do `print(int(100**0.5))`...

Comment: @Riker, "That addition statement adds 1 to m (the counter) only when (x+1) is a perfect square."

Comment: @Ben oh, didnt see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the exact question posed: since we know that **1** is a perfect square and all integers between that and the maximal one (here **9**) will be included we can simply find that maximal one:

```python
print((100-1)**.5//1)
```

(`//1` performing integer division by one to remove any fractional part may be replaced with `/1` prior to Python 3.)

with both endpoints (an inclusive `start` and exclusive `stop` equivalent to a `range`) this could be extended to a function (negative inputs catered for with `max`):

```python
f=lambda start, stop:print(max(0,stop-1)**.5//1-max(0,start)**.5//1)
```

Comment: Ah, that's a good bit of math to solve the problem. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, below is another approach using additions and multiplications only.

The square of ***N*** is the sum of the ***N*** first odd positive integers:

```
1^2 = 1
2^2 = 1 + 3 = 4
3^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
4^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16
etc.
```

Consequently, if we are to compute all perfect squares up to a given limit, each one can be quickly deduced from the previous one.

Hence the following possible algorithms:

```python
# with 3 variables, using addition only
s = i = 1
n = 0

while s < 100:
  n += 1
  i += 2
  s += i

print(n)
```

```python
# with 2 variables, using addition and multiplication
s = 1
n = 0

while s < 100:
  n += 1
  s += n * 2 + 1

print(n)
```

Or as a recursive lambda:

```python
f = lambda x, s=0, n=0: f(x, s+n*2+1, n+1) if s < x else n-1

print(f(100))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works (47 chars):

```
print(sum(map(lambda n:0==n**.5%1,range(100))))
```

`n**.5` will return a float, which will be a whole number if n is a perfect square. We can then do `%1` to get the fractional part, which will be `0` if `n` is a perfect square, so adding `0==` will give us a boolean of whether or not `n` is a perfect square.

We can then make that into a `lambda` function and `map` that onto the range, which will give us a list of booleans, which can be summed to give us how many `True` values were there.

As in Ben Frankel's answer, it's actually shorter to use list comprehension than `map`. I didn't think of that. That gets us down to 41 chars.

```
print(sum(0==n**.5%1for n in range(100)))
```

EDIT: removed one byte by replacing `not` with `0==`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
print(sum(x==int(x**.5)**2for x in range(1,101)))
```

This is a sum of boolean values, so they are treated as `0` for `False` and `1` for `True`.

EDIT: As in Riker's answer, `x**.5%1==0` is shorter than `x==int(x**.5)**2`.